# Ruby select method selecting values that do not meet criteria

Tags: ruby, string, ienumerable

Have the following code which should select every other character of a string and make a new string out of them:

```
def bits(string)
  string.chars.each_with_index.select {|m, index| m if index % 2 == 0}.join
end
```

However, select returns this output with test case "hello":

```
"h0l2o4"
```

When using map instead I get the desired result:

```
"hlo"
```

Is there a reason why select would not work in this case? In what scenarios would it be better to use map over select and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use `select`, try this.

```
irb(main):005:0> "hello".chars.select.with_index {|m, index| m if index % 2 == 0}.join
=> "hlo"
```

`each_with_index` does not work because it is selecting both the character and the index and then joining all of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), you will return an array having one element for each character in the string.

```
arr = "try this".each_char.map.with_index { |c,i| i.even? ? c : nil }
  #=> ["t", nil, "y", nil, "t", nil, "i", nil]
```

which is the same as

```
arr = "try this".each_char.map.with_index { |c,i| c if i.even? }
  #=> ["t", nil, "y", nil, "t", nil, "i", nil]
```

My initial answer suggested using [Array#compact](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) to remove the `nil`s before joining:

```
arr.compact.join
  #=> "tyti"
```

but as @npn notes, `compact` is not necessary because [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-join) applies [NilClass.to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_s) to the `nil's`, converting them to empty strings. Ergo, you may simply write

```
arr.join
  #=> "tyti"
```

Another way you could use `map` is to first apply [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to pass pairs of characters and then return the first character of each pair:

```
"try this".each_char.each_cons(2).map(&:first).join
  #=> "tyti"
```

Even so, [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-select) is preferable, as it returns only the characters of interest:

```
"try this".each_char.select.with_index { |c,i| i.even? }.join
  #=> "tyti"
```

A variant of this is:

```
even = [true, false].cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [true, false]:cycle> 
"try this".each_char.select { |c| even.next }.join
  #=> "tyti"
```

which uses [Array#cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle) to create the enumerator and [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to generate its elements.

One small thing: [String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) is more memory-efficient than [String#chars](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-chars), as the former returns an enumerator whereas the latter creates a temporary array.

In general, when the receiver is an array,

- use `map` when you want to return an array containing one element for each element of the receiver.
- use [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) when you want to return just one element of the receiver.
- use `Array#select` or [Array#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) (or [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) or [Enumerable#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) if the receiver is an enumerator).

Me, I'd use a simple regular expression:

```
"Now is the time to have fun.".scan(/(.)./).join
  #=> "Nwi h iet aefn"
```

Comment: I don't think you don't actually need to call compact to remove the nil's from the array before joining.  #join, class #to_s on each element, and NilClass has a to_s method that returns "".  So I don't think it's the case of relying on undocumented behavior to skip the .compact call.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that select does not work in this case is that select "Returns an array containing all elements of enum for which the given block returns a true value" (see the doc [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)), so what you get in your case is an array of arrays [['h',0],['l',2],['o',4]]  which you then join to get "h0l2o4".

So select returns a subset of an enumerable.  map returns a one to one mapping of the provided enumerable. For example the following would "fix" your problem by using map to extract character from each value returned by select.

```
def bits(string)
  string.chars.each_with_index.select {|m, index| m if index % 2 == 0}.map { |pair| pair.first }.join
end

puts(bits "hello") 
=> hlo
```

For lots of reasons this is not a good way to get every other character from a string however.

Here is another example using map.  In this case each index is mapped to either the character or nil then joined.

```
def bits(string)
  string.chars.each_index.map {|i| string[i] if i.even? }.join
end
```